# how to insert new records each year without using mysql events

Tags: php, mysql

my aim is to be able to incriment student form each year
i.e form 1 next year to be form 2.i tried using **mysql events **but seem to be complicated for my situation.
i have the following tables

```
 id       student_id        form      year
----------
  1       2013-04-04888       1        2013
  2       2013-04-01920       2        2013
```

after **one year** i want to have something like this

```
id       student_id       form       year
----------
1       2013-04-04888       1        2013
2       2013-04-01920       2        2013
3       2013-04-04888       2        2014
4       2013-04-01920       3        2014
```

any one with the idea or suggestion on how i can do in this the proffesional way

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a process that runs once a year, I'd create an external process that runs that query (one more page in your admin module, if this is a web app, or something similar depending on what you're doing); that way, users can control exactly when it happens, and also it is very simple to implement.

Comment: I'd agree with okaram, an external scheduled task (cron job etc) is likely to be the way forward here as then you can specify precisely when each year it runs and all that kind of thing.  Really the query you are running basically `INSERT INTO students (student_id,form,year) SELECT student_id,MAX(form)+1,MAX(year)+1 FROM students GROUP BY student_id;`

Comment: You can create a php page, increment_year.php that would run your query; the end user then needs to visit this page, so you make sure the admin has a link to it in your menus etc. Another option is a cron/at job, but I'd be weary of scheduling something a year in advance :) Also, you can figure out a way to calculate that year, so you store year of entry, and you calculate based on today's date

Answer (score 0):

A cron job or some other agent maybe?

The insert would be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO people(student_id,form,year)
SELECT student_id,max(form)+1,max(year)+1
FROM people
WHERE form < 10 -- or something
GROUP BY student_id
```

Comment: thenx @werner waage...but on which file can i put this code, coz i have alot of files on this web application.....plz help

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a poor database design here.  You have a student, and for each student you want to know what form they are in.  You seem to have access to the year they joined, and so you could store a "form 1" year.

For sake of precision lets say that the form year starts on the 1st of April.

The database table would look like

```
students (
     -- added an int primary key for use later
     id INT PRIMARY,
      -- update this as needed
     student_id VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE ,
     yearStartedForm1 INT UNSIGNED
)
```

Using your example you might have the following records

```
id    student_id       yearStartedForm1
1     2013-04-04888    2013
2     2013-04-01920    2012
```

From this "form 1" year you could then calculate their current year by using something like the following two.  Firstly if you wanted to replace form>4 with 'completed'

```
SELECT
    d.id,
    d.student_id,
    IF(d.form > 4,'completed',d.form) AS form,
    d.yearStartedForm1
FROM (
    SELECT
        s.id,
        s.student_id,
        v.currentFormYear - s.yearStartedForm1  + 1 AS form,
        s.yearStartedForm1
    FROM students s,(
        SELECT IF(MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)<4,YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)-1,YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)) AS currentFormYear
    ) v
) d
```

Secondly if you wanted to limit form to a max of 5

```
SELECT
    s.id,
    s.student_id,
    LEAST(v.currentFormYear - s.yearStartedForm1  + 1,5) AS form,
    s.yearStartedForm1
FROM students s,(
    SELECT IF(MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)<4,YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)-1,YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)) AS currentFormYear
) v
```

This would give you the current form number dynamically without the need for duplicate rows.  Of course you could change yearStartedForm1 into a DATE field easily enough, and work off DATEDIFF or similar functions.  The idea is still the same, as at present you are duplicating each student row when in fact all you are trying to do is derive a form number based on time having elapsed.

Comment: wow this is it...but can u help me to select  just years not including dates, coz all students starts at the same day in a year, even he started days later but assumed to hav started with other students in that form.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that comment I'm afraid, as in what you are looking to select/

Comment: ooooh now i gat u ,i was just confused with myself...thenx in advance

Comment: but 1 more thing is wen form=4, i need stop incrimenting yearStartedForm1, i want when form>5, form=Completed

Comment: Use of another subquery can do that, see above.  This will check if form is > 4, and if so then it outputs 'completed'.  Alternatively one what limits to a max of 5 (if you want to keep it numeric) using LEAST()